# How can I dynamically specify the return data model from dio in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

#### Description of the problem

How to ensure `dio` return the response data in a specific data model when I need to exchange data using the Internet?

For example, all the response content is the type of `application/JSON`, and fits the following rules:

- Field `code` is an integer between 0 and 1000.
- Field `message` is a text with optional tip messages which might be `null`.
- Field `timestamp` is a timestamp for the current time in seconds.
- Field `data` is optional data that could be any type and might be null.

So, I defined the model in the following codes:

```dart
class ResponseModel<T> {
  late final int code;
  late final int timestamp;
  late final String? message;
  late final T? data;
}
```

All response data got by `dio` are stored in a `Map` which is the type of `_InternalLinkedHashMap` and cannot be converted by specifying the return type in a method signature like this:

```dart
Future<Response<ResponseModel>> request() {
    // Access data from the Internet by using `dio` and return
}
```

Then how can I store the response data in the model `ResponseModel` in `dio`?

#### What I tried

While I was searching some documents, I found I can convert the data by a named constructor. Since the model contains a generic type, I cannot make a standard convert function for it.

#### Related codes

```dart
class ResponseModel<T> {
  /*
    some fields
   */

  ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    code = json['code'] as int;
    timestamp = json['timestamp'] as int;
    if (null != json['message']) {
      message = json['message'] as String;
    }
    // how to convert the data?
  }
}
```

Comment: Ran into this problem after a backend API change.  Did you ever find a decent way to do this?  My current method is very inefficient and ugly.